# Initializing JS components at the end of HTML or on "onload"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, initialization

For a while I had been running JavaScript component initialization by waiting for the "onload" event to fire and executing a `main()` of sorts.  It seemed cleaner and you could be sure the ID state of your DOM was in order.  But after some time of putting that through its paces I found that the component's initialization was choked off by any sort of resource hanging during the load (images, css, iframes, flash, etc.).

Now I have moved the initialization invocation to the end of the HTML document itself using inlined `<script />` execution and found that it pushes the initialization before other external resources.

Now I wonder if there are some pitfalls that come with doing that instead of waiting for the "onload".

Which method are you using?

**EDIT**: Thanks.  It seems each library has a specialized function for `DOMContentLoaded`/`readyState` implementation differences.  I use prototype so [this](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/document/observe) is what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, we use jquery, and its document ready state ensures that the DOM is loaded, but is not waiting for resources like you say.  You can of course to this without a javascript framework, it does require a function you can create for example: [document ready](http://snipplr.com/view/6156/documentready/)  Now, for the most part putting script at the end of the page sure ensure the rest of the page is there, but making sure the DOM is ready is never a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery has $(document).ready()

The ideal point at which to run most scripts is when the document is ready, and not necessarily when it is "loaded".

[See here](http://encosia.com/2009/03/25/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

Answer (score 1):

I use neither.  Instead, I depend on [YUI's onDomReady()](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#ondomready) (or onContentReady()/onAvailable()), because it handles the timing of initialization for me.

(Other JS libraries have similar methods for executing only once the page is fully loaded, as this is a common JS problem.)

Answer (score 1):

That is not conform to any (X)HTML spec and I would be advised against that. It would put your site in to a quirks mode of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way around the issue would be to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which isn't supported in all browsers. Hacks (eg polling `doScroll()` or using `onreadystatechange`) exist, so libraries are able to provide this functionality across browsers.

But there are still problems with `DOMContentLoaded` and chunked transfers which haven't been addressed by popular JavaScript frameworks.

Here's [my take on the issue](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks-docs/raw-file/tip/domcontentloaded-en.html).